# Highlight jquery datepicker dates

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Please help me to solve these below issues in jquery datepicker

I want to high light the start date of the week,if any date with in that week have values .

Ex: If I have the value as 4th july(or any date in 1st week),then 1st july only  should be high lighted in jquery datepicker

I want to gigh light the start date of the month, if any date with in that month have values

Ex: If I have the value as 10 th july(or any date in july),then 1st july only  should be high lighted in jquery datepicker

Comment: You should also refer to the plugin that you are using. There are plenty of [date pickers in jquery](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=jquery+datepicker)

Comment: If you want; a good answer, regarding some particular piece of code... your best bet is to provide said code. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I've been using the [BootStrap DatePicker](https://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter), I think it has some better functionality, than you're run off the mill jQuery datepicker.

[image: datepicker]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/i4me15xj.lrh.png))</sub>

Bonus, if you understand jQuery; you can modify the script fairly easily.. to perform other tasks.